# Saving ANSI codes from dialog command into a file

Tags: bash, escape-characters, ansi

Is it possible to get dialog command, example:

```bsh
dialog --title "HELLO" --yesno "Are you sure?" 6 30
```

into a file with all ANSI escape codes, so it can be printed later?

You can redirect the dialog into a file to get the output but you can't interact with the page, so it may be hard to exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `script`:

```
script -q -c 'dialog --title "HELLO" --yesno "Are you sure?" 6 30'
```

`dialog` will run interactively, so you’ll be able to exit easily, and even track screen changes made in response to user input if you with (`script` supports timestamps, which can be useful here).

The output will be stored in a file named `typescript`; you can change that by specifying a file name on the command line. The file might contain start and end lines:

```
Script started on ...
Script done on ...
```

Remove those if necessary, and you’ll be left with `dialog`’s output, including escape codes.

Comment: Perfect, actually on Ubuntu it saved just the ANSI codes without any extra messages.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken I've redirected the output into a file that contained the output, but it also created typescript file with the extra output. And it seems that this also works with just dialog, but script will make interactive dialog still work. I will change the question a bit. So it will better match this answer.